# React Native - Difference between onChange vs onChangeText of TextInput

Tags: react-native

I'm not sure when to use `onChange` vs `onChangeText` in a `TextInput` component. I know `onChangeText` accepts the changed text as an arg in the callback, but is that why you would use `onChangeText`, since you can then update state within the callback?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

**UPDATE 26.08.2019**

Since the initial version of the answer, TextInput's API has changed, and answer below is no longer valid. I haven't worked with react-native for more than 2 years now, so I can't really tell which version had these changes.

Regarding the answer, `onChangeText` is still a simple prop, that gives whatever is the value of the input field on every change.

`onChange` on the other hand, passes an event with `{ nativeEvent: { eventCount, target, text} }` (as mentioned in the comment to this answer). Now, I cannot tell with confidence, why do you need `eventCount` and `target`. I can only state, that `eventCount` is increased every time you interact with `TextInput` component (character added, removed, all deleted, value pasted) and `target` is a unique integer for that TextInput field. And `text` is the same value as in `onChangeText`

So basically, I would suggest to use `onChangeText`, as a more straight forward prop.

If you want to accomplish functionality like in the old answer(below), you can create custom component, that wraps `TextInput` and receives custom properties and passes them to the `onChange` prop later. Example below:

```
const MyTextInput = ({ value, name, type, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <TextInput
      value={value}
      onChangeText={text => onChange({ name, type, text })}
    />
  );
};
```

And then use it whenever you need to use `TextInput`

```
handleChange(event) {
    const {name, type, text} = event;
    let processedData = text;
    if(type==='text') {
        processedData = value.toUpperCase();
    } else if (type==='number') {
        processedData = value * 2;
    }
    this.setState({[name]: processedData})
}

<MyTextInput name="username" type="text" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleChange}}>
<MyTextInput name="password" type="number" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange}}>
```

**OLD ANSWER**

`onChangeText` is basically a simplified version of `onChange`, so you can easily use it, without the hassle of going through `event.target.value` to get changed value.

So, when should you use `onChange` and when `onChangeText`?
If you have simple form with few textinputs, or simple logic, you can go straight away and use `onChangeText`

```
<TextInput value={this.state.name} onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({name: text})}>
```

If you have more complicated forms and/or you have more logic in handling data (like handling text differently from number) when user changes input, then you are better of with `onChange`, because it gives you more flexibility. For example:

```
handleChange(event) {
    const {name, type, value} = event.nativeEvent;
    let processedData = value;
    if(type==='text') {
        processedData = value.toUpperCase();
    } else if (type==='number') {
        processedData = value * 2;
    }
    this.setState({[name]: processedData})
}

<TextInput name="username" type="text" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleChange}}>
<TextInput name="password" type="number" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange}}>
```

Comment: As I know there is no prop called name in the TextInput of React Native. For react this is ok. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html

Comment: @Shanaka you can inject the name... but also doesn't have the property value at nativeEvent.

Comment: There is also no prop named `type` in React Native as well, in case anyone is searching for it too.

Comment: `nativeEvent` has none of those properties. `{ nativeEvent: { eventCount, target, text} }`

Answer (score 2):

`onChangeText` gives you just the string as the argument for the callback.

`onChange` gives you the synthetic event as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
<Input label='First Name' onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.first}/>
```

```
onChange = (event) => {    
  const {eventCount, target, text} = event.nativeEvent;
  this.setState({first:text});
};
```

The `target` attribute seems useless. It doesn't look like you can attach data attributes to react-native elements and retrieve them from the target element like you can in react because the app is not a browser.

With react, we're told it's better practice to **not** attach inline functions to the onChange event for performance reasons.  We're supposed to use custom props or data-* attributes on the HTML element and retrieve the information from **e.target** inside the onChange handler.

But with react-native it seems this format of passing data is actually acceptable:

```
<Input 
      label='First Name' 
      onChangeText={text=>this.onChange('first',text,'anotherValueIWantToPass')} 
      value={this.state.first}/>
```