# Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.username')

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ui-kitten

I'm rookie in React Native, Just started Learning it.
I want to build Android App using React Native.

Now, I have a basic login form which will send fetch request to server and show if user is authorized or not.

but when I try to Alert the value of input field it throws error "Undefined is not an object"

I am referring to official docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-text-input) , This code is working.
I have also tried basic react form [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) .
I am using [UI kitten text input](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/#/docs/ui-components/rktextinput) for inputs, I have also used native react TextInput, it gave same error.

My current code is:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Alert, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
import {RkButton, RkText, RkTextInput, RkCard} from 'react-native-ui-kitten';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: ''
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;

    this.setState({
      username: target.username,
      password: target.password
    });
  }


  login()
  {
    Alert.alert(this.state.username) //getting error here

    let data = {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      mode: 'same-origin',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password
      }),
      headers: {
        'Accept':       'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }
    }
    fetch('http://demourl.com/login',data)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      if (responseJson.success == 'true') {
        Alert.alert('Login Successfull!')
      }
      else {
        Alert.alert('Login Failed')
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
    ;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <RkCard style={{padding: 20}}>
          <View style={{alignItems: 'center',padding: 10}}>
            <RkText rkType='warning large' style={{fontSize: 40}}>Log In</RkText>
          </View>
          <View style={{alignItems: 'center',padding: 10}}>
            <RkTextInput placeholder='Username' value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <RkTextInput placeholder='Password' value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          </View>
          <View style={{alignItems: 'center',padding: 10}}>
            <RkButton rkType='success small' title="Press Me"
              onPress={this.login}
            >Log In!</RkButton>
          </View>
        </RkCard>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 65,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 10
  },
});
```

Please tell me where I'm failing to understand the working. or where my code is buggy.
Thanks In advance.

Comment: change `onPress={this.login}` to `onPress={() => this.login()}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the `login` function as you did for `handleChange` or use `arrow` function like

```
login = () => {
  ...
}
```

Take a look at the arrow function document [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Hope this will help!

Comment: I did binding of login function in my constructor as this.login=this.login.bind(this);...the error is gone now..thanks....but I still cant access username in alert...it showing blank....I alert target.username in my handlechange function...its blank there also...how can i access my input in handlechange function...is my code wrong for doing so?

Comment: Sorry, I never worked with this library, but as per their code, you can pass any valid props of TextInput, so if you need just the text then use `onChangeText`. Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44416541/react-native-difference-between-onchange-vs-onchangetext-of-textinput

Comment: onChangeText worked for me...Thank You!