# React-native TextInput value receiving object but I am clearly passing it a string?

Tags: javascript, react-native, textinput

```
state={username:"",password:""}
```

...

```
<TextInput style={styles.inputStyle}
    placeholder='email123@mail.com' 
    autoCorrect={false}
    value={this.state.username}
    onChange={text =>{ 
        this.setState({username:text});
        console.log(this.state.username);
    }}
/>
```

The error I'm getting is value is being passed an object, and it cites the line this textInput begins, but I don't see how this is possible

Styles is just:

```
let styles ={
    titleStyle:{
      fontWeight:'bold',
      fontSize: 20,
      textAlign:'center'
    },
    inputStyle:{
      backgroundColor:'#d4d4d4'
    }
}
```

Inside the render.

Comment: What's `styles.inputStyle`? Can you show us the full code? Also can you tell us the full error message?

Answer (score 2):

The `onChange` will return you an object, if you use `onChangeText`, it will return the value directly.

```
<TextInput 
    style={styles.inputStyle}
    placeholder='email123@mail.com' 
    autoCorrect={false}
    value={this.state.username}
    onChangeText={text => this.setState({ username: text })}
/>
```

Or, if you want to use the `onChange` you can do it in this way:

```
<TextInput 
    style={styles.inputStyle}
    placeholder='email123@mail.com' 
    autoCorrect={false}
    value={this.state.username}
    onChange={event => this.setState({ username: event.target.value })}
/>
```

Read [React Native - Difference between onChange vs onChangeText of TextInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44416541/react-native-difference-between-onchange-vs-onchangetext-of-textinput)

Answer (score 1):

Use onChangeText instead of onChange.

Answer (score 0):

Try to this code:
                 `onChange={this.onUserChange}`

`onUserChange = (e, {value}) => {
        if (value)
        this.setState({username:value})
    }`