# How to make e.target.value in React-native?

Tags: react-native

I am transferring React to React Native.
But I am sticked to the problem using e.target.value.
This is a code of React that works well.

```
  _searchContact = (e) => { this.state.keyword 
    this.setState({
      keyword : e.target.value
    });
  }

ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ

    <input
      name="keyword"
      placeholder="Search"
      value={this.state.keyword} 
      onChange={this._searchContact} 
    />
```

And I tried to write again with the way of React-native
But it doesn't work.

```
  _searchContact = (e) => { 
    this.setState({
      keyword : e.nativeTarget.value
    });
  }

      

     <TextInput
        style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
        name="keyword"
        placeholder="Search"          
        onChangeText={this._searchContact}        
        value={this.state.keyword} 
    />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `onChangeText` you'll have to use an anonymous function and pass in 'text' like so

```
(text) => this._searchContact(text)
```

And instead of passing e into your method pass test in as a parameter and set keyword equal to text.

```
 _searchContact = (text) => { 
 this.setState({
  keyword : text
 });
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!. But  must onChange be changed to onChangeText in react-native?

Comment: No entirely sure that it's necessary to use onChangeText as I am newer to react native as well. From what this is saying it's possible by using event.nativeEvent.vale? Haven't tried it but seems possible.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44416541/react-native-difference-between-onchange-vs-onchangetext-of-textinput/44421126

Comment: It works well. And I think It should be used with onChangeText

Answer (score 1):

Just use `e` as the value and set it to `keyword` in setState.

Your code should work only with the below code:

```
_searchContact = (e) => { 
    this.setState({
      keyword : e
    });
  }
```

Actually `onChange` and `onChangeText` are both fired when text input's text changes, but `onChange` doesn't provide the changed text, its just a mere intimation callback, so to extract value of the current text being typed, `onChangeText` gives a callback with the changed text as the param for the callback.

For reference read [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#onchange).