# Not able to pass an event parameter with my this.handleChange in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state, react-props

I keep getting the error undefined is not an object (evaluating 'event.preventDefault)

Clearly i am not aloud to give an event parameter on this.handleChange on my child component that is rendered in the parent component.

Why i don't know.  Been following a few online examples and they al did quite the same thing so I don't know why it's impossible to use (event) in my handleChange function.

```
// Parent component //

export class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  state = {
    name: ""
  };

  handleChange = event => {    // so this event causes problems ... 
                               // when i skip event i get my console.log
                               // and don't receive any errors
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("handleChange has fired");
    this.setState({
      name: event.target.value
    });
    console.log(this.state.name);
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.name);
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MainTitle message={"Bienvenue " + this.state.name} />
        <InputField getNewName={this.handleChange} />
        <PrimaryButton text={"button"} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}


// Child component //

class InputField extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { getNewName } = this.props
    return (
      <TextInput
        placeholder={"Please enter your name"}
        onChangeText={() => getNewName()}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default InputField;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native - Difference between onChange vs onChangeText of TextInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44416541/react-native-difference-between-onchange-vs-onchangetext-of-textinput)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you don't need the `native event` object in your TextInput, because you want to use onChangeText which is perfect for your use case and easier to use. But you should pass the new value to your this.props.getNewName like this:

```
<TextInput
  style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
  onChangeText={(newText) => this.props.getNewName(newText)}
  value={....}
/>
```

see here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput
And your handler should not expect the event, but the newText passed from child TextInput:

```
handleChange = newTextHere => {
  console.log("handleChange has fired", newTextHere);
  this.setState({
    name: newTextHere
  });
  console.log(this.state.name);
};
```

Comment: I'm getting the updated state in my window now! Worked lik a charm, thanks a lot.

Comment: Still wondering though why i'm not able to use something like e.preventDefault() within this context ... Quite new to react native so still not getting the big picture of state and props i guess

Comment: No problem. So I would appreciate if you can tag this as the answer.

Comment: From the link I shared. Look at the documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#onchange vs onChangeText.

Comment: @brunelli, it does not provide an event object probably: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#onchangetext and you can see `onChange` right below this link.