# how to make a 'number' component in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to make a 'number' component which accepts numbers on input.
I tried to make it, but it is not working.

Here the code-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';

    constructor(props)
    {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: ''
    };}

   handleInputChange = (text) => {
    if (/^\d+$/.test(text)) {
      this.setState({
        text: text
      });
    }
  } 

  const NumberInput = (props) => {
          return (
      <TextInput
        keyboardType='numeric'
        onChangeText={this.handleInputChange}
        value={this.state.text}
      />
    )
  }
 export { NumberInput };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have access to `this` in functional component, you need to define it as class based component,

```
class NumberInput extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: ''
    };
  }

  handleInputChange = (text) => {
    if (/^\d+$/.test(text)) {
      this.setState({
        text: text
      });
    }
  } 

  render(){
    return (
      <TextInput
        keyboardType='numeric'
        onChangeText={this.handleInputChange}
        value={this.state.text}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

---

**Update**

You can also try this,

```
<TextInput
   keyboardType='numeric'
   onChange={this.handleInputChange}  //onChange instead of onChangeText
   value={this.state.text}
/>
```

And your function should be,

```
handleInputChange = (e) => {
  if (/^\d+$/.test(e.target.value)) {
     this.setState({
        text: e.target.value
     });
  }
}
```

[Reference to this change.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44416541/react-native-difference-between-onchange-vs-onchangetext-of-textinput)

Comment: after making it and writing it like this `<NumberInput placeholder="Phone No"
      maxLength={10}
      style={styles.myText}
      onChangeText={
        Phone => this.setState({Phone})
    
      }
      keyboardType={'numeric'} />` , it is not dispaying on the screen

Comment: I think we don't have `NumberInput` in react native, you can do this `<TextInput type="number">`.

Comment: here I am using  `NumberInput` as a custom component

Comment: here my mistake was that I was not appling style on it. it is working now

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use Number() function to check if the input is a number. It not, it will return NaN

Answer (score 0):

you should use the class component  when to use the constructor and use super or use and used hock function with useState in react

```
     class NumberInput extends Component{
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          text: ''
        };
      }


      handleInputChange = (text) => {
        if (/^\d+$/.test(text)) {
          this.setState({
            text: text
          });
        }
      } 

      render(){
        return (
          <TextInput
            keyboardType='numeric'
            onChangeText={this.handleInputChange}
            value={this.state.text}
          />
        )
      }
    }
```

or using the following shape when used the function component

```
    import useState from'react'

        function NumberInput (){
      const [text, setText] = useState('');


      handleInputChange = (text) => {
        if (/^\d+$/.test(text))(setText(text)) ;

        }
      } 

        return (
          <TextInput
            keyboardType='numeric'
            onChangeText={this.handleInputChange}
            value={text}
          />
        )
      }
    }
```