# Is it possible to disable certain keys from keyboard react-native

Tags: android, react-native

How to disable specific keys from keyboard ' **react-native android** '.

Comment: it is not possible to disable them on the keyboard but you can create an event listener on your input to ignore your specific chars.

Comment: @behrad Okay thanks for your quick response. Can you please share how to do this, I have spend more time with this.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44421126/9474700

Answer (score 0):

Short answer no,
You need to create your own keyboard as element (jsx),you can put it in modal and you can disable react native keyboard or another choice is to filter the input from keyboard