# Why isn't @testing-library/react-native fireEvent calling my onChange function?

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-testing-library

I've looked at a number of different StackOverflow questions regarding issues with testing library fireEvent, and in every case, it seems the post was resolved by fixing poor handling of props or something similar.

I can't seem to spot any issues with my code however, and I'm wondering if this is perhaps a configuration issue. I'm expecting my mock function to have been called, however, it's not being called and I'm not sure why. Any help would be much appreciated. I've simplified my code as much as possible below to an example case.

## Foo.js

```
import {TextInput} from "react-native";

const Foo = (props) => {
    return <TextInput testID={"test"} onChange={() => props.onChange()} />
}

export default Foo;
```

## Foo.test.js

```
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react-native';
import Foo from "./foo";

test('onChange works properly', () => {
    const onChangeMock = jest.fn();
    render(<Foo onChange={onChangeMock} />)
    fireEvent.changeText(screen.getByTestId("test"), 'myTest');
    expect(onChangeMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

Running this test outputs:

```
Error: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0
```

Answer (score 2):

After some experimentation, I've identified that in a react-native application, changing a TextInput component fires both an OnChange and an OnChangeText event. This means you can link a function to either onChange or OnChangeText (though the event object included in each is structured differently. See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44421126/7910304) for details).

```
<TextInput testID={"test"} onChange={() => props.onChange()} />
```

vs.

```
<TextInput testID={"test"} onChangeText={() => props.onChange()} />
```

However, using fireEvent in @testing-library/react-native fires only the event specified and DOES NOT fire the sister event. This means if you're watching for an onChange event in your component, you must use the following:

```
fireEvent(screen.getByTestId("test"), 'change', {target: {value: 'abc'}});
```

And if you're watching for an onChangeText event, you must use the following:

```
fireEvent.changeText(screen.getByTestId("test"), 'abc');
```